# how to change frame width in emacs?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I have recently begun to run emacs in `-nw` mode and ran in into a problem when I started to open up more than 2 frames. The third frame became really crapped in between. So I wonder how I can change the frame width like I could do when I used emacs' GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean windows, not frames, since a frame means another X window in X mode, and functions more like saving and restoring the window state in text mode.

You can click on the window status line and drag it just like you can in X ( if your terminal supports a mouse ), or you make the current window taller with `C-x ^` and wider/narrower with `C-x {` and `C-x }` respectively.

Comment: I searched google and found out that you have to use `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` to get emacs register mouse clicks. However I still can't adjust the width after that. But I can now click on the code to point the cursor, and can mark the text. Your suggested commands doesn't work for me either. is it `C-x /` for adjusting the width?

Comment: No, C-x { to make the window narrower and C-x } to make it wider (note that C-x { is: CTRL+x then SHIFT+[) Works perfectly well, you can also pass numeric arguments to it to change the amount it moves, see here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html

Comment: Right, I forgot xterm-mouse-mode isn't on by default.  I turn it on my .emacs file.  Once it is on you can just click and drag the vertical divider between the windows to resize, but you don't see the resize as you drag -- only once you release.